# having troubles getting !any() query to work with raven db

Tags: linq, ravendb

I am new to RavenDB and it's been frustrating try to get the Any() LINQ query to work correctly.  Here is what my document looks like:

```
{
  "Key": "BKey",
  "Text": "B Key",
  "IsLocal": false,
  "Category": null,
  "_destroy": false,
  "Translations": [
    {
      "CultureCode": "es-ES",
      "Text": null
    },
    {
     "CultureCode": "ja-JP",
     "Text": "Hello"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would expect the following query to give me all entries that don't have translations for "es-ES":

```
var nonTranslatedEntries = 
_docs.Query<ResourceEntry>().Where( e => e.Translations == null || e.Translations.Count == 0 || !e.Translations.Any(t => t.CultureCode == "es-ES" && t.Text != null))
```

However, this isn't working.  It's bringing back the entries even when a translation for the specified CultureCode exists.  It works if I have only have one item inside the translations array.  But as soon as I have more than one item inside the translations array, then the query stops working.

As an alternative solution, I tried to do the following:

```
var translatedEntries =  from re in _docs.Query<ResourceEntry>()
                                    where re.Translations.Any(t => t.CultureCode == cultureCode && t.Text != null)
                                    select new {Id = re.Id};
var translatedIds = translatedEntries.ToList().Select(e => e.Id).ToList();

var nonTranslatedEntries = 
  _docs.Query<ResourceEntry>().Where(e => !e.Id.In(translatedEntryIds));
```

But that just brings back an empty list.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Nizar

Comment: What version of RavenDB are you running?

Comment: Saw your post in the google group.  Appears to be a bug.  It's been reported. http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-732

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static index that will get the job done:

```cs
public class Resources_ByTranslation : 
    AbstractIndexCreationTask<ResourceEntry, Resources_ByTranslation.IndexEntry>
{
    public class IndexEntry
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string CultureCodes { get; set; }
    }

    public Resources_ByTranslation()
    {
        Map = entries => from entry in entries
                         select new {
                                     entry.Key,
                                     CultureCodes = entry.Translations
                                                     .Where(x => x.Text != null)
                                                     .Select(x => x.CultureCode)
                                    };
    }
}
```

Then query with:

```
var nonTranslatedEntries =
    session.Query<Resources_ByTranslation.IndexEntry, Resources_ByTranslation>()
           .Where(x => x.CultureCodes != "es-ES")
           .As<ResourceEntry>();
```

Note that the CultureCodes list is being treated as single string.  This is due to how then index matching works internally.  It's slightly strange, but it does work.

Comment: Matt, that doesn't bring back the correct results either.  Here is what the Lucene query looked (via Intellisense): {(-CultureCode:es\-ES AND CultureCode:*)}.  I had to solve the issue via another method that I posted as the answer to this question.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing my issue as follows:

Upon creation of a resource entry, I go ahead and create all the possible translations and set the translation text to null:

```
{
  "Key": "BKey",
  "Text": "B Key",
  "IsLocal": false,
  "Category": null,
  "_destroy": false,
  "Translations": [
    {
      "CultureCode": "es-ES",
      "Text": null
    },
    {
     "CultureCode": "ja-JP",
     "Text": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I then created the following index:

```
public class ResourceEntries_ByCultureCodes : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ResourceEntry>
    {
        public ResourceEntries_ByCultureCodes()
        {
            Map = entries => from e in entries
                             select new
                                 {
                                     e.Id,
                                     e.Key,
                                     e.Text,
                                     e.IsLocal,
                                     e.Category,
                                     _ = e.Translations.Select(t => CreateField(t.CultureCode, t.Text != null, false, true))
                                 };
        }
}
```

That gives me a flat record of translations with the value set to 'true' if a translation exists for a that specific culture.  For example, I get back something like this:

```
{ 
   Id,
   Key,
   Text,
   IsLocal,
   Category,
   es-ES: <true> or <false> depending upon whether Translation.Text != null
   ja-JP:<true> or <false> depending upon whether Translation.Text != null
}
```

I can then do LuceneQuery as follows to get all entries for "es-ES" that have NOT been translated:

```
_docs.LuceneQuery<ResourceEntry, ResourceEntries_ByCultureCodes>().WhereEquals("es-ES", false);
```

I wish there were an easier solution, though.